# Problem typing nested navigators react navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I've got a tab navigator that has `Home` and `Profile` as screens. `Home` is a stack navigator that contains `RestaurantDetails` and `RestaurantList` as screens.

I have a `Button` that is in the `RestaurantList` screen. I want to navigate to `RestaurantDetails`.

Button.tsx

```
const Button = ({name}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate("RestaurantDetails", {name})
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   
  )
}
```

The problem is that typescript complains

```
Argument of type '["RestaurantDetails", { name: string}]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: "Home", params: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList, Readonly<{ key: string; index: number; routeNames: string[]; history?: unknown[] | undefined; routes: NavigationRoute<ParamListBase, string>[]; type: string; stale: false; }>>] | [screen: ...] | [screen: ...] | [screen: ...] | [screen: ...]'.
  Type '["RestaurantDetails", { name: string}]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Profile", params: undefined]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type '"RestaurantDetails"' is not assignable to type '"Profile"'.
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that typescript looks in `TRootParamList` instead of `HomeStackParamList` for the `RestaurantDetails` screen, since if I add `RestaurantDetails` to `TRootParamList` typescript stops complaining. However, I am unsure on how to actually stop this problem.

types.ts

```
import { NavigatorScreenParams } from '@react-navigation/native';

type QueueDetailsParams = {
  name: string
};

type HomeStackParamList = {
  RestaurantDetails: QueueDetailsParams | undefined;
  RestaurantList: undefined
};

type TRootParamList = {
  Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList>;
  Profile: undefined
};

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends TRootParamList {}
  }
}
```

P.S
I know that I can replace my `onPress` with the below but would rather not do this.

```
const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Home", {screen: "RestaurantDetails", params: {name}})
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `useNavigation` hook, you have to type it with the StackNavigationProp and the param list that includes the target screen:

```js
const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<HomeStackParamList>>();
```

Then you can use it with any screen in that param list:

```js
navigate('RestaurantList');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to work. Is there any way to do this without typing `useNavigation`?. I like having `useNavigation` automatically typed for me. e.g. The way react navigation's `namespace ReactNavigation` automatically types `useNavigation`.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if importing navigation from props solves your problem, if not we can debug it further:

```
const Button = ({name,navigation}) => {
  const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate("RestaurantDetails", {name})
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would prefer to use the `useNavigation` hook in this scenario